# Comparing file content

Tags: python, parsing, file-io

I have a script that generates several output files (ex: out0.txt to out250.txt) and I want to be able to compare a specific value from all of them and output the top 10 highest, specific, values in all of them.

For example, *in each of these output files* there are multiple lines containing various data, the lines I am interested are the ones that contain, on its own line, the match statistics. Here's an example extract from one of the files.

```
 ....
 Score
 Matches: 592 (52.3%) #the 52.3 part of the 592 portion
 Ref: 1 GT......
 Query: 340
 Matches: 584 (54.5%)  #and this for 54.3
```

Specifically, I am interested in the percentage part as I would like to display only the top 10 highest percentages in all of the files.

**I have split files before/taken in specific data, but typically relied on line number**. Unfortunately the location of these 'matches' lines is a bit more irregular and not every 3rd line or so.

Should **I try to have the program look for numbers next to a % symbol**, considering it's the only part of the file's output information that provides that?

In short, how do I extract only the value of percentage portions from all the files, amidst other string output, to then compare it and output the 10 highest?

Thank you,

Comment: I think you can use the regular expressions to extract the data from files and then use inbuilt sort to get the items in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

def get_values_from_file(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    winpat = re.compile("([\d\.]+)\%")

    values = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.find("Matches") >=0:
            percn = float(winpat.findall(line)[0])
            values.append(percn)

    return values

all_values = []    
for filename in ["out0.txt", "out1.txt"]:
    values = get_values_from_file(filename)
    all_values += values

all_values.sort()
all_values.reverse()
print(all_values[0:10])
```

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the file it seems the data you looking for is always starts with `Matches`, so using `str.startswith()` find these lines. Then using regex, you can find out the percentage values. Sample code (Python 2):

```
import re

with open('my_file') as input_file:
    percent_lines = filter(lambda x: x.startswith('Matches'), input_file)

percent_regex = re.compile(r'([\d.]+%)')

for line in percent_lines:
    print percent_regex.findall(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = """Score
Matches: 592 (52.3%) #the 52.3 part of the 592 portion
Ref: 1 GT......
Query: 340
Matches: 584 (54.5%)  #and this for 54.3
"""
exp = re.compile("Matches: [0-9]+ \\(([0-9|\\.]*)\\%\\)")
matches = exp.findall(s)
print(matches) #['52.3', '54.5']
```

Comment: What about other output files?